# How to create isolated session for ConversationBufferMemory per user in Langchain?

Tags: session, caching, chatbot, large-language-model, py-langchain

**Problem Statement**

I wish to create a FastAPI endpoint with isolated users sessions for my LLM, which is using ConversationBufferMemory. This memory will serve as context for conversation between the AI and the user. Currently, it's been shared with the AI and all users. I wish instead to isolate the memory per user.

I have the base implementation of the `Langchain` core library below.

**Boilerplate Code**

```
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.chains import ConversationChain

memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", k=12)

async def interview_function(input_text):
    prompt = PromptTemplate(
        input_variables=["chat_history", "input"], template=interview_template)
    chat_model = ChatOpenAI(model_name="gpt-4-1106-preview", temperature = 0, 
                        openai_api_key = OPENAI_API_KEY, max_tokens=1000)
    llm_chain = ConversationChain(
        llm=chat_model,
        prompt=prompt,
        verbose=True,
        memory=memory,
    )
    
    return llm_chain.predict(input=input_text)
```

I made progress by subclassing the ConversationChain with the intention of passing custom memory keys, which are related to the user's unique id, from a separate data store, like a SQL table, which I use to reference the various users interacting with my LLM.

**Subclassing Progress**

```
def create_extended_conversation_chain(keys: List[str]):
    class ExtendedConversationChain(ConversationChain):
        input_key: List[str] = Field(keys)

        @property
        def input_keys(self) -> List[str]:
            """Override the input_keys property to return the new input_key list."""
            return self.input_key

        @root_validator(allow_reuse=True)
        def validate_prompt_input_variables(cls, values: Dict) -> Dict:
            """Validate that prompt input variables are consistent."""
            memory_keys = values["memory"].memory_variables
            input_key = values["input_key"]
            prompt_variables = values["prompt"].input_variables
            expected_keys = memory_keys + input_key
            
            if set(expected_keys) != set(prompt_variables):
                raise ValueError(
                    "Got unexpected prompt input variables. The prompt expects "
                    f"{prompt_variables}, but got {memory_keys} as inputs from "
                    f"memory, and {input_key} as the normal input keys."
                )
            return values
    return ExtendedConversationChain
```

However, I am stuck in creating this custom memory key.
My memory keys seem to be not accessible after they have been defined at instantiation as I did in my boilerplate code section.

Is there a Langchain specific solution or do I need to create my own Cache and have my LLM interact with it ?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, a dictionary solves the issue temporarily I noticed.

```
user_memory_dict = {}

async def interview_function(input_text: str, user_id: int):
    if user_id not in user_memory_dict:
        user_memory_dict[user_id] = ConversationBufferMemory(
            memory_key="chat_history", k=12
        )

    memory = user_memory_dict[user_id]
    prompt = PromptTemplate(
        input_variables=["chat_history", "input"], template=interview_template
    )
    chat_model = ChatOpenAI(model_name="gpt-4-1106-preview", temperature=0,
                            openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY, max_tokens=1000)
    llm_chain = ConversationChain(
        llm=chat_model,
        prompt=prompt,
        verbose=True,
        memory=memory,
    )
    
    return llm_chain.predict(input=input_text)
```

#### As a sidenote

For production purposes this "dictionary" should be replaced by an External Cache Store, such as Redis. This will result into faster transactions by the server, while also a lower CPU utilization rate, which would translate to a more light weight application.